# Mixture of multivariate gaussian distribution tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, mixture-model, tensorflow-probability

As said in the title, I am trying to create a mixture of multivariate normal distributions using tensorflow probability package.

In my original project, am feeding the weights of the categorical, the loc and the variance from the output of a neural network. However when creating the graph, I get the following error:

> components[0] batch shape must be compatible with cat shape and other component batch shapes

I recreated the same problem using placeholders:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp # dist= tfp.distributions 

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()

l1 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='observations_1')
l2 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='observations_2')

log_std = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('log_std', [1, 2], dtype=tf.float32,
                                          initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0),
                                          trainable=True)

mix = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,1], name='weights')

cat = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=[mix, 1.-mix])
components = [
    tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=l1, scale_diag=tf.exp(log_std)),
    tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=l2, scale_diag=tf.exp(log_std)),
]

bimix_gauss = tfp.distributions.Mixture(
  cat=cat,
  components=components)
```

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong? I looked into the error and it seems `tensorshape_util.is_compatible_with` is what raises the error but I don't see why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you provided a mis-shaped input to `tfp.distributions.Categorical`. It's `probs` parameter should be of shape `[batch_size, cat_size]` while the one you provide is rather `[cat_size, batch_size, 1]`. So maybe try to parametrize `probs` with `tf.concat([mix, 1-mix], 1)`.

There may also be a problem with your`log_std` which doesn't have the same shape as `l1`and `l2`. In case `MultivariateNormalDiag` doesn't properly broadcast it, try to specify it's shape as `(None, 2)` or to tile it so that it's first dimension corresponds to that of your location parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When the components are the same type, MixtureSameFamily should be more performant.

There you only pass a single Categorical instance (with .batch_shape [b1,b2,...,bn]) and a single MVNDiag instance (with .batch_shape [b1,b2,...,bn,numcats]).

For only two classes, I wonder if Bernoulli would work?