# How to use tfp.density.Mixture with JointDistributionCoroutine

Tags: python, tensorflow, montecarlo, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to define a model function for MCMC.
The idea is to have a mixture of two distributions controlled with a probability ratio.
One of my attempts would look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

root = tfd.JointDistributionCoroutine.Root

def model_fn():
    rv_p     = yield root(tfd.Sample(tfd.Uniform(0.0,1.0),1))

    catprobs = tf.stack([rv_p, 1.-rv_p],0)
    rv_cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=catprobs)

    rv_norm1  = tfd.Sample(tfd.Normal(0.0,1.0),1)
    rv_norm2  = tfd.Sample(tfd.Normal(3.0,1.0),1)

    rv_mix = yield tfd.Mixture(cat=rv_cat,
                     components=[
                        rv_norm1,
                        rv_norm2,
                     ])

jd = tfd.JointDistributionCoroutine(model_fn)
jd.sample(2)
```

The code fails with:

```
ValueError: components[0] batch shape must be compatible with cat shape and other component batch shapes ((2, 2) vs ())
```

Could you give me an example of how to use Mixture distribution in a way that allows "any" shape of inputs?

I'm using tensorflow 2.4.1 and tensorflow_probability 0.12.1 with python 3.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixture of multivariate gaussian distribution tensorflow probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314556/mixture-of-multivariate-gaussian-distribution-tensorflow-probability)

Comment: This is going in the right direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. For reference here is a sample code:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

import numpy as np
from time import time

numdata = 10000
data = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,numdata).astype(np.float32)
data[int(numdata/2):] = 0.0
_=plt.hist(data,30,density=True)

root = tfd.JointDistributionCoroutine.Root
def dist_fn(rv_p,rv_mu):
    rv_cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=tf.stack([rv_p, 1.-rv_p],-1))
    rv_norm  = tfd.Normal(rv_mu,1.0)
    rv_zero =  tfd.Deterministic(tf.zeros_like(rv_mu))
    
    rv_mix = tfd.Independent(
                tfd.Mixture(cat=rv_cat,
                            components=[rv_norm,rv_zero]),
                reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)
    return rv_mix


def model_fn():
    rv_p    = yield root(tfd.Sample(tfd.Uniform(0.0,1.0),1))
    rv_mu   = yield root(tfd.Sample(tfd.Uniform(-1.,1. ),1))
    
    rv_mix  = yield dist_fn(rv_p,rv_mu)
    
jd = tfd.JointDistributionCoroutine(model_fn)
unnormalized_posterior_log_prob = lambda *args: jd.log_prob(args + (data,))

n_chains = 1

p_init = [0.3]
p_init = tf.cast(p_init,dtype=tf.float32)

mu_init = 0.1
mu_init = tf.stack([mu_init]*n_chains,axis=0)

initial_chain_state = [
    p_init,
    mu_init,
]

bijectors = [
    tfb.Sigmoid(),  # p
    tfb.Identity(),  # mu
]

step_size = 0.01

num_results = 50000
num_burnin_steps = 50000


kernel=tfp.mcmc.TransformedTransitionKernel(
    inner_kernel=tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
    target_log_prob_fn=unnormalized_posterior_log_prob,
    num_leapfrog_steps=2,
    step_size=step_size,
    state_gradients_are_stopped=True),
    bijector=bijectors)

kernel = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
    inner_kernel=kernel, num_adaptation_steps=int(num_burnin_steps * 0.8))

#XLA optim
@tf.function(autograph=False, experimental_compile=True)
def graph_sample_chain(*args, **kwargs):
  return tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(*args, **kwargs)


st = time()
trace,stats = graph_sample_chain(
      num_results=num_results,
      num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
      current_state=initial_chain_state,
      kernel=kernel)
et = time()
print(et-st)


ptrace, mutrace = trace
plt.subplot(121)
_=plt.hist(ptrace.numpy(),100,density=True)
plt.subplot(122)
_=plt.hist(mutrace.numpy(),100,density=True)
print(np.mean(ptrace),np.mean(mutrace))
```